# How to add array list with custom class

Tags: android, arrays, string, class

I have created an array list like below. But I don't want to input the values like this. Rather I want to use array list from resources.

```
sArrayList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    sArrayList.add(new Empl("ABC", 24));
    sArrayList.add(new Empl("ACB", 24));
    sArrayList.add(new Empl("BVF", 28));
    sArrayList.add(new Empl("BRT", 28));
    sArrayList.add(new Empl("ANM", 23));
```

This my custom class

```
public class Empl {

     private String name;
     private int age;

     public  Empl(String name,int age){
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
     }    
     public String getName(){
      return name;
     }    
     public int getAge(){
      return age;
     }
    }
```

My string array are as following:

```
  <string-array name="story_name_array">
        <item>To Build a Fire</item>
        <item>The Gift of the Magi</item>
        <item>The Winepress</item>
        <item>"THE BET"</item>
        <item>"The Boarded Window"</item>
        <item>"A Coward"</item>
</string-array>
<integer-array name="num">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
</string-array>
```

**Now how can I add values from string array resources in the arraylist with the custom class?**

Answer (score 0):

Access the Array from the resource using.

```
String[] myStrings =
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.story_name_array);

String[] myNum =
    getResources().getIntArray(R.array.num);
```

Now loop on first or second array(note the same size).

after that create object and add them in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[]  nameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.story_name_array); // for getting the array from resources
 String[] ageArray   = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.num); 

 for(int i =0; i<nameArray.length; i++) 
     sArrayList.add(new Empl(nameArray[i] , Integer.valueOf(ageArray[i]) )); // for adding it to your sArrayList
```

Try the above solution .

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Empl> empls = new ArrayList<Empl>()

String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.story_name_array);
String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.num);

if(names.length == numbers.length) {
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        empls.add(new Empl(names[i],Integer.valueOf(numbers[i]));
    }
} else {
    Log.d(" Names and number array size does not match!");
}
```